# What does java return in resultset in case of mysql update query

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I need to know did the update query go wrong or right, i know how to do it in PHP, but have no idea in java (I'm new to java).

Comment: returns the number of rows affected

Comment: but what if the query went wrong? i mean how can i fetch true or false like in php?

Comment: 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Comment: Returns the number of rows affected if query is ok if it is wrong it will return -1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It returns:

1. The number of affected rows in the resultset if the query is a DML query (insert, update, delete)
2. 0, if the query is a DDL (create, alter, etc.)

See the javadoc for more details: [Execute Update Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29)

And I strongly advise you to read the related section in [JDBC Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), read the section titled: Return Values for the executeUpdate Method

Comment: only answer backed up with reference, up to now ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you execute an `UPDATE`, you should not use `executeQuery`, as an update does not produce a resultset. In general you should use [`executeUpdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE`. This method returns an update count.

If the query fails (that is: if an error occurs), then the JDBC driver will throw an `SQLException`. If the query ran, but didn't update any rows that doesn't mean it failed, there simply weren't any rows to update, so the update count will be 0.

Also I'd advise you to follow the [JDBC Basics Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) and check the Javadocs of the classes in the [package `java.sql`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/package-summary.html).